# how to get string from object in php

Tags: php, simplexml

here is the `var_dump` of object:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#31 (1) { [0]=> string(70) "/0.jpg" }
```

I want to have just `/0.jpg` as string...

I want to have it inside `$img`.

I used

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
```

Comment: what have you tried beyond loading the XML? Have you checked the examples section in the manual? Have you searched for SimpleXML on Google or even on StackOverflow? Right now this sounds like gimme teh codez.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple XML creates objects. In my experience, the quickest way to reassign a string value is to cast it.

For example:

```
$image = (string)$simplexmlobj->some_element[0];
```